# How can you iterate through the list of websites in the search engine in Python?

Tags: python, web, web-scraping

When you search something on your browser it will give you by default a list of websites related to the search that you have done, but I was wondering if there was a way to store/print/iterate the list of urls shown in that main page.

I haven't tried anything because I don't even know which python library should I use.

Which library should I use for this puprose?

I hope that  it is a valid question.

Answer (score 0):

`Beautiful Soup`

`Requests`

`Selenium`

1. Pick your poison.
2. Read the docs.
3. ???
4. Profit!

Comment: I don't think this is the right way to answer!

Comment: @Xitiz I don't think SO is for asking peoples' opinions about what library to use for a specific type of task...

Comment: Then you should say/suggest, ask to edit  in comment rather then writing answer!  And additionally I haven't found "poison" word is good word in that sentence. As [merriam-webster dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/poison) says "poison" mean _" a substance that through its chemical action usually kills, injures, or impairs an organism"_